# Location of shared templates in Django 1.7

Tags: python, django

I have a base template `base.html` in the folder `project_name/templates/` but my templates in my app directories can't locate shared templates in `project_name/templates/`. I think it's probably because I haven't specified `TEMPLATE_DIRS` in `settings.py`. But `TEMPLATE_DIRS` seems to have been removed from `settings.py` since Django 1.6. Why was it removed? Is it more correct to place my shared templates in another directory? I know I can configure Django in many ways but I want to learn 'the most vanilla Django' way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Just add the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` to the `settings.py`.  This is the standard and correct way in django up to 1.7:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
)
```

This setting was removed from the default `settings.py` to make this file as small as possible.  It contains only vital settings and `TEMPLATE_DIRS` is not the one of them.

Comment: Okay thanks. But if I'm using `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),` I will need to place the templates folder outside my project directory instead of `project_name/templates`. Is this correct or should I make a constant `PROJECT_DIR`?

Comment: Which version of django you use?  In 1.7 default `settings.py` has a `BASE_DIR` pointing to the directory with the `manage.py` file.  So your `templates` will be in the same dir.

Answer (score 2):

(Using Django 1.8) You can add the path from @catavaran 's answer above to the **'DIRS'** key of the **TEMPLATES** variable in settings:

```py
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

given`BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))`